# Split a string in Perl

Tags: string, perl, split

I am trying to split a string in Perl such as below :-

```
String = "What are you doing these days?"

Split1 - What 
Split2 - are 
Split3 - you 
Split4 - doing these days?
```

I want the first n number of words separately and the rest of the line together in a separate variable.

Is there any way to do this ? There is no common delimiter I can use. Any help is appreciated ! Thanks.

Comment: See [`perldoc -f split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html). Note the arguments .. also the special `" "` pattern discussed therein is likely applicable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perl's split has a limit parameter that seems to be just what you want.  To split off the first $n words and leave the rest together, use $n+1 as the limit (the result will be at most $n+1 elements):

```
my $n = 3;
my $string = "What are you doing these days?";
my @words = split / /, $string, $n+1;
print "$_\n" for @words;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
($string1, $string2, $string3, $rest) = split (/ /, $instring, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex to split the string according to your requirement

```
$ip_tring = "What are you doing these days?";
if($ip_tring =~ m/(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(.*)/)
{
    print("1=$1,2=$2,3=$3,4=$4\n");
}
else
{
    print("no match...\n");
}
```

Comment: *Wayyyy* not lazy enough.